# KeyError : 1 is occurs while make replace value for the datesets

Tags: python, dictionary, dataset, keyerror

I'm working on a dataset and make it clear to learn the model, but when I changing the str into integers there is an error occurs.

```
TIMEPERIOD = {'Morning': 1,'Afternoon': 2,'Evening' : 3,'Night' : 4}
df.TIMEPERIOD = [TIMEPERIOD[item] for item in df.TIMEPERIOD]
```

The Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-9db3f99347ba> in <module>
----> 1 df.TIMEPERIOD = [TIMEPERIOD[item].copy for item in df.TIMEPERIOD]

<ipython-input-96-9db3f99347ba> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 df.TIMEPERIOD = [TIMEPERIOD[item].copy for item in df.TIMEPERIOD]

KeyError: 1
```

Comment: Post df or df.TIMEPERIOD.

Comment: There is a column which name is the same as a variable name.

Comment: Yes. What is the content of that column? The column has a value `1` in it, you are using this value `1` as a key for the variable, but it throws error because value `1` is not a key in variable.